# NGINX ingress auth-url returning 404 but the endpoint exists

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-windows, nginx-ingress, docker

Adding the annotation:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://my-auth-service.my-api.svc.cluster.local:8080
```

...to my ingress rule causes a 500 response from the ingress controller (the ingress works without it).

The service exists and I can ssh into the ingress controller and CURL it, getting a response:

`curl http://my-auth-service.my-api.svc.cluster.local:8080` Produces a 200 response.

I checked the ingress controller logs but it says that the service returned a `404`. If I can CURL to the same URL why would it return a `404`?

```
2019/07/01 20:26:11 [error] 558#558: *443367 auth request unexpected status: 404 while sending to client, client: 192.168.65.3, server: localhost, request: "GET /mocks HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

I'm not sure what to check to deterine the problem.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, for future readers - I ran into the same problem, and after looking at my auth service logs, noticed nginx ingress' requests were appending a /_external-auth-xxxxxx path to the request url.

Here's where the ingress controller does it, in the source:

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/internal/ingress/controller/template/template.go#L428

And how [I'm handling it](https://github.com/oliverbarnes/liquid-voting-auth/commit/9bf59d890f0bc27c7957768417ece1cf8e53501b) in my own auth service (a Elixir/Phoenix route):

```
get "/_external-auth*encoded_nginx_auth_url", TokenController, :index
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options you should check:

1. **Global External Authentication**

According to this [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#global-external-authentication):

> By default the controller redirects all requests to an existing
>   service that provides authentication if global-auth-url is set in the
>   NGINX ConfigMap. If you want to disable this behavior for that
>   ingress, you can use enable-global-auth: "false" in the NGINX
>   ConfigMap. nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-global-auth: indicates
>   if GlobalExternalAuth configuration should be applied or not to this
>   Ingress rule. Default values is set to "true".

2. **Server Name Indication**

Check your `proxy_ssl_server_name` setting in nginx. It indicates if HTTPS uses SNI or not and it is set to false by default.

Please let me know if that helped.